# Get OAuth Request token from Flickr using Dispatch?

Tags: scala, oauth, scala-dispatch

How could I get request token from Flickr using Dispatch Scala library? Is it possible using Dispatch to get base string? and sign requests?

Comment: Uh, why not use a Oauth library for Scala?

Comment: I can't find any library that supports maven.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with dispatch:

```
private def buildSearchReq(searchTerm: String, lat: Double, long: Double): Req = {
  val consumer = new ConsumerKey(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
  val requestToken = new RequestToken(token, tokenSecret)
  val req = url(searchUrl)
    .addQueryParameter("term", searchTerm)
    .addQueryParameter("radius_filter", "40000")
    .addQueryParameter("ll", s"$lat,$long")
  new SigningVerbs(req).sign(consumer, requestToken)
}
```

There are more functional ways to put this together; however, this one doesn't look like a cat walked across your keyboard.